# javah непосредственно магия

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jni

Есть у меня файл .java который хранится по вот такому пути `D:\IdeaProjects\twain\src\sample` называется он `SetingsController.java`. Утилита `javac` и тому подобные хранятся по такому пути `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin.` Собственно из `CMD` перехожу в каталог `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` вызываю `javac` `D:\IdeaProjects\twain\src\sample\SetingsController.java`, получаю в этом же каталоге `D:\IdeaProjects\twain\src\sample\` файл `SetingsController.class`. Дальше из `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin` вызываю `javah -jni` `SettingsController` а так же разные варианты типа `sample.SetingsController` и получаю

> Error: cloud not find class file for SetingsController

Очевидно, по моему. При этом, если я из той же директории вызову `javah -jni Java.lang.Object`, я получаю заголовочный файл `Java_lang_Object.h` Пробовал указывать `-classpath` `D:\IdeaProjects\twain\src\sample\` со всевозможными точками двоеточиями и прочими символами, тот же результат. В роликах видел переход из командной строки в каталог с проектом, попробовал и получил ошибку типа `javac` не является внутренней или внешней командой, и я абсолютно согласен с этим. вот код файла что бы было видно в каком пакете находится класс.

```
package sample;
public class SetingsController {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SetingsController");
    }

    native public int select(String message);
}
```

В связи с выше перечисленным у меня есть несколько вопросов.

1. Какой должен быть путь к `.class` файлу из `javah`.
2. Каким образом умельцы из видео вызывают javac/javah из каталога проекта используя несуществующие пути.
3. На сколько структура проекта созданная в `Eclipce` отличается от структуры проекта созданного в `IntellijIDEA` и как выйти из этой ситуации.

Comment: добавьте каталог "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin" в список PATH, и выполняйте указанные действия прямо в каталоге с сорцами.

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо большое, выручил конкретно. Всё заработало получил заголовочный файл ))